# Convert an adult's Google account to a child's account

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-family-link

I have created my daughter a Gmail account and accidentally entered the wrong DOB. I'm trying to add this account to my Family Link, however, it's not allowing me to manage this account via the Family Link. I am also now unable to change the DOB as it cannot be under the age of 13.

I have created my Son a Gmail account with the correct DOB, (under 13) and this can be managed via the Family Link.

Is there any way to alter my daughter's account so its the same as my son's and I can manage both via the Family Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set it up on minimum **13** and maybe you will manage to trigger Google's Age Filter Check which will disable your daughter's account and hopefully unlock it for parent control. This works only for 30 days since account creation. After this 30-day grace period account shall be deleted.

- **https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1333913**
- **https://support.google.com/families/answer/7103262**

Next step would be adding supervision to the account in order to link it with the Family Link:

- **https://support.google.com/families/answer/9055704**

> [image: 9]

---

Also, you can try to switch regions to trigger child status and then manage it via the Family Link (every country has different quotas for adulthood)

> [image]

- **[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/age-of-majority-by-civil-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority#Civil_law)**
- **https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1350409**

Comment: Hi, I have tried to set my daughters account to 13 which then disabled the account.  However,  going back into the family link,  there is no option there to manage the account.  or to change who manages the account.

Comment: @Simon you need to add supervision to that account: https://support.google.com/families/answer/9055704

Comment: Almost there.  I can now supervise the account and parental controls,  however, im unable to change the DOB to anything under the age of 13 without it disabling. I need to change it so that i am the manage for that account. I cannot see any options to change the manager?

Comment: @Simon if **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8CLO.png)** wont work then you cant, but I still believe you can trick it if you change your country as I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 5):

Simon, it took me forever to find this, but this link appears to work. As long as your child's account birth date is under 18 years old.

https://families.google.com/supervision/intro

First you sign into the parent account, and then the child account. The child account then "approves" supervision, and effectively becomes a managed child's account.

There is still no way to set the age below 13, but at least you will be able to manage the account as a parent!

Comment: Yes, but doesn't solve the problem. Thanks still.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get away from this was by creating a new child account from the Family link app itself and setting the age < 13. But it then requires a lot of things to fix afterwards which a child may have associated with their old Google account - contacts etc.