# How do I recover an account that was converted to a Google "kids" account and immediately blocked?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-family-link

I have created an account for my 9-year-old girl. Then I found out that creating a kids account was possible. So I tried to convert that account into a kids account by modifying date of birth, When I did so, Google asked if 9 years old was correct, I said yes, and immediately, the account was blocked. How can I prove I created this account and how do I recover it? Who to contact?

Comment: Related : [Convert an adult's Google account to a child's account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123804/88163)

Answer (score 2):

If age is set on less than 13 years, an account will be blocked and deleted in the next 30 days.

**https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1333913**

To recover such account you need to set up supervision:

> [image]

**https://support.google.com/families/answer/9055704**